# Get a set of property values for all ancestors

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to find an efficient way to get a set of property values for the ancestors of a node. Consider the following trivial setup:

```
CREATE 
(a {id:'a'}), (b {id:'b'}), (c {id:'c'}), (d {id:'d', age:10}),
(b)-[:HAS_PARENT]->(a),
(c)-[:HAS_PARENT]->(a),
(d)-[:HAS_PARENT]->(b),
(d)-[:HAS_PARENT]->(c)
```

I'd like to get a set with the id of `d` and all of the ids along any path between `d` and `a` along with some other properties of `d`.

I've come up with this:

```
MATCH (d {id:'d'})
OPTIONAL MATCH path=(d)-[:HAS_PARENT*]->()
RETURN d.age as age,
(REDUCE(o = [], r IN (collect (extract (n in nodes(path) | n.id))) | o + r)) AS closure
```

Which doesn't quite work because it doesn't keep the values in `closure` unique and also seems incredibly inefficient. If I leave off this path matching and instead just project the ID of `d` and then perform the same traversal myself with the Java API:

```java
for (Path path: graphDb.traversalDescription()
                .depthFirst()
                .relationships(RealtionshipNames.HAS_PARENT, Direction.OUTGOING)
                .uniqueness(Uniqueness.NODE_GLOBAL)
                .traverse(graphDb.getNodeById(nodeId))) {
    ids.add((String)path.endNode().getProperty("id"))
}
```

the task completes in seconds, even with my larger dataset (100k nodes, 200k relationships). With my Cypher query, it never completes.

Is there a way to merge this all into a single, efficient Cypher query or am I better off doing some post processing with the Java API?

Comment: What exactly should the query return? Is it ('d', ['b', 'a']) and ('d', ['c', 'a'])? Or ('d', ['b', 'c', 'a'])? Or something else?

Comment: @zaboco it should return the set ('d', 'c', 'b', 'a').

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want the parent's IDs for now:

```
MATCH (d {id:'d'})
OPTIONAL MATCH path=(d)-[:HAS_PARENT*]->(p)
WHERE NOT (p)-[:HAS_PARENT]->()
RETURN d.age, d.id, collect(NODES(path))
```

The `WHERE NOT (p)-[:HAS_PARENT]->()` is to only return paths through all the way to the first ancestor and not intermediate paths.

This would return you a row for each path through the tree from d to head ancestor, which I don't think is exactly what you want. You could couple it with `UNWIND` to pull out the unique IDs into a collection using a `WITH` statement though.

If all you want is the IDs with no real concern about the pathways, you could use:

```
MATCH (d { id:'d' })
OPTIONAL MATCH path=(d)-[:HAS_PARENT*]->(p)
RETURN d.id, d.age, COLLECT(DISTINCT p.id)
```

If you need the head in the collection then change the last line to:

```
RETURN d.id, d.age, d+ COLLECT(DISTINCT p.id)
```

Comment: Thank you. The latter is exactly what I'm looking for. Works great for the smaller query but when I query the entire dataset it still never completes. Any performance thoughts?

Comment: You should use a label, e.g. `:Node` for your tree elements. And then create an index for :Node(id) which is then used by cypher. Or use `MATCH (d) WHERE id(d) = {node_id}`